# Compute combination of a pair variables for a given operation in R

Tags: r, feature-engineering

From a given dataframe:

```
# Create dataframe with 4 variables and 10 obs
set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame(replicate(4,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
```

I would like to compute a **substract operation** between **in all columns combinations by pairs**, but only keeping one substact, i.e `column A- column B` but not `column B-column A` and so on.

What I got is very manual, and this tend to be not so easy when there are lots of variables.

```
# Result
df_result <- as.data.frame(list(df$X1-df$X2,
df$X1-df$X3,
df$X1-df$X4,

df$X2-df$X3,
df$X2-df$X4,

df$X3-df$X4))
```

Also the colname of the feature name should describe the operation i.e.(x1_x2) being `x1-x2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combn:

```
COMBI = combn(colnames(df),2)
res = data.frame(apply(COMBI,2,function(i)df[,i[1]]-df[,i[2]]))
colnames(res) = apply(COMBI,2,paste0,collapse="minus")

head(res)
  X1minusX2 X1minusX3 X1minusX4 X2minusX3 X2minusX4 X3minusX4
1         0         0        -1         0        -1        -1
2         1         1         0         0        -1        -1
3         0         0         0         0         0         0
4         0         0        -1         0        -1        -1
5         1         1         1         0         0         0
6        -1         0         0         1         1         0
```